# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Assertion failed

Tags: python, selenium, timeoutexception

I have a problem with Selenium Webdriver, trying to locate the element, the program gives an error    "raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:     Assertion failed"

My code is with a page-object model: 
My code: 
1st part -

```
  def located_element(self, locator):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        return element
```

2nd part

```
 def enter_email(self, user):
        email_field = self.located_element(self.locator.Email)
        email_field.click()
        email_field.send_keys(Users.get_user(user)["email"])
```

3rd(running)

I have tried some recommendations from related issues but it didn't help me. At first, it couldn't find the element, that's why I added EC, but now it raises an error. Please, help me, how can I handle the Exception. I have tried the locator both with xpath and css-selector too.

Comment: Post the relevant html and the locator you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The css selector I used - Email = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input-error") and Xpath = "//input [@class = 'input-error']"    and html:  <input placeholder="" autocomplete="" type="email" name="email" class="input-error">

Comment: The selector looks ok, I'm guessing it's inside `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: let me copy the whole html code:  
    
<script>
    gbCommonInfo.pageType = 'login'
</script>
<div class="outermost-vue-loading vue-loading-login j-vue-loading-login"></div>
<div class="c-login container-fluid-1200 j-login-container she-v-cloak-none" v-cloak>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="c-forgotpsd col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" v-show='forgetPassword.showForm'>
    <h2>Forgotten Password</h2>
There aren'n any tags here.

Comment: Does `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input-error")))` work? try it directly, without passing it as a parameter.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it raises the same error.

Comment: @Guy it still has the same error, I checked it one more time.

Comment: Than it's in `<iframe>`, or you are not in the correct page when trying to locate it. Can you share the link?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I try to click on the email field here https://www.shein.com/user/auth/login?direction=nav

Answer (score 0):

In the first time you open the site the email field doesn't have class `input-error`. Try

```
email_field = self.located_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-login-source="loginPage"] [name="email"]'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed it, now it works well.